# Determining which signal interrupted my system call (Linux)

Tags: c, linux, signals

After my system call has returned because it was interrupted by a signal, is there a way to determine exactly which signal type (i.e. child process termination) caused the interruption?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a number of facilities in Linux to deal with signals:

- [`waitpid(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid) could be used to wait inline for `SIGCHLD`

  [`sigaction(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sigaction) could be used to setup handler functions to react to specific signals, the `SA_RESTART` flag here affects whether *certain* system calls are *interrupted* or *restarted*

  [`sigprocmask(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sigprocmask) could be used to block a number of signals

  [`sigwait(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sigwait) could be used to wait for number of signals inline

  Latest kernels support [`signalfd(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/signalfd), which is convenient when one needs to combine signal handling and non-blocking IO.

Then there's the whole next level of complexity when we start talking about threads, though if you deal with signals explicitly you usually don't really care *which* signal interrupted the system call.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set an handler. Have a look [here](http://linux.die.net/man/2/signal).